# How to set a proxy for a JBoss Instance

Tags: java, jboss, proxy

I have a JBoss instance running and I would like to route all traffic through a proxy.

I have tried setting the System Properties to load in run.sh as so:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 $JAVA_OPTS"`

But it seems JBoss ignores these as I still am not able to route through the proxy.

Any help?

Comment: What is the version u r using?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `standalone.xml` after

```
</extensions>
```

add the following

```xml
<system-properties>
    <property name="http.proxyHost" value="yourProxyIpAddress"/>
    <property name="http.proxyPort" value="yourProxyPort"/>
    <property name="http.nonProxyHosts" value="localhost"/> <!-- if you want to ignore localhost -->
</system-properties>
```

Comment: I typically use standalone.xml

Comment: I have added below xml in standalone.xml file <system-properties>
        <property name="http.proxyHost" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="http.proxyPort" value="8090"/>
    </system-properties>. Still i am not able to route my traffic from 8585(jboss) to 8090 (apache proxy server)

Answer (score 3):

Take care if yor connections are http or https, because there is also a flag for https? Also you can set a blacklist (nonproxyhosts)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: I believe the settings are just http.proxyHost and https.proxyHost respectively for each set of parameters