# error deploy struts on jboss 6.1.0

Tags: java, jboss, struts-1

When I deploy every my project's war file built using struts-1 on JBOSS 6.1.0, I always get the following error

```
ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3Struts.war state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3Struts.war
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. @ http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglib_1_1.dtd[1,3]
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///D:/javaKHANH/JavaKit_t.Khanh/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EJB3Struts.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): 
org.xml.sax.SAXException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. @ http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglib_1_1.dtd[1,3]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to format your question and start a first attempt to reduce your console output to the relevant part.

Comment: I am new member ... Sorry you :( I need a help

Comment: I edited your post for you. Next time try to format your post accordingly so that viewers can actually read relevant information from your post easily and thus respond effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

This type of exception occurs when a corrupt, missing or inaccessible DTD is referred to by your document.

First I would like you to verify that any DTD referred to by your application is actually online and available.

If your application validates a document by reading the DTD from the internet, JBoss will need internet access. Also make sure that your proxy settings are correct as they should be to allow access to outside DTD documents via JBOSS. Add `-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourproxy` if you're using a proxy.

Comment: How to add -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourproxy. Can you help me.

Comment: I havent worked much with JBOSS6, but take a look into this post. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799165/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-a-jboss-instance)